# Merge hashes with value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say I have the following array of hashes

```
[
  {
    created: '11/11/86',
    amount: 10,
  },
  {
    created: '11/11/86',
    amount: 20,
  },
  {
    created: '12/11/86',
    amount: 4,
  }
]
```

I want to merge all hashes with the same `created` key so the result would be:

```
[
  {
    created: '11/11/86',
    amount: 30,
  },
  {
    created: '12/11/86',
    amount: 4,
  }
]
```

I realise I can use loops but I am looking for something more elegant.

The hashes could have more keys, but I only care about these 2.

Comment: Have you tried something? What's can be more elegant than a loop?

Comment: Therein lies my question. I have it working with the loop but wondering if there is a better way

Comment: Better than what? Could you share your solution?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages and "[mcve]". We'd like to see what you tried toward solving this, either as what pages you searched and why those didn't work, or your code attempt and why it's not doing what you want. Without those it looks like you're asking for us to do your work for you. "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/128421)" will help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with `map` and `sum` (*since you are using rails*):

```
arr.group_by{|x| x[:created]}.map{|date, x|
  {
    created: date,
    amount: x.sum{|xx| xx[:amount]}
  } 
}

# => {:created=>"11/11/86", :amount=>30}, {:created=>"12/11/86", :amount=>4}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [
  {
    created: '11/11/86',
    amount: 10,
  },
  {
    created: '11/11/86',
    amount: 20,
  },
  {
    created: '12/11/86',
    amount: 4,
  }
]

arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |g,h| h[g[:created]] += g[:amount] }.
  map { |k,v| { created: k, amount: v } }
  #=> [{:created=>"11/11/86", :amount=>30}, {:created=>"12/11/86", :amount=>4}]
```

The first step is:

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |g,h| h[g[:created]] += g[:amount] }
  #=> {"11/11/86"=>30, "12/11/86"=>4}
```

`Hash.new(0)` is sometimes referred to as a *counting hash*. See the class method [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-c-new).